# MKMapView setRegion: causes app to crash in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, zooming

I want to zoom `MKMapView` on custom coordinates. So I using following code.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D myCurrentLocationCordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longtitude);
[myMapView setCenterCoordinate:myCurrentLocationCordinate animated:YES];
MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(myCurrentLocationCordinate, 500, 500);
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [myMapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];
[myMapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
```

But my app is randomly crashing on `setRegion:` Method. And getting this log when it is crashing :-

> adjustedRegion description: (MKCoordinateRegion) adjustedRegion = {
>   center = (latitude = 23.066432958888399, longitude =
>   72.531898498535213)   span = (latitudeDelta = 0.0051205743267423998, longitudeDelta = 0.0048793707173899747) }

Also sometimes getting following error :-

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: '(null) must implement title when canShowCallout is YES on
>   corresponding view >'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x18e8b91b8 0x18d2f055c 0x19ab76244 0x19abb2c74 0x19ab74d44 0x19ab8db58 0x19477c7dc 0x19abb041c
>   0x19abb0290 0x19abb1588 0x1001ae010 0x1001ad318 0x101265258
>   0x101265218 0x101275080 0x101274b78 0x18d94b2a0 0x18d94ad8c)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

I am sure not why it is crashing randomly. Let me know if any other proper solution for zooming the `MKMapView` on custom coordinates.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same issue, but solved using this

```
 CLLocationCoordinate2D startCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitudeAPI, longtitudeAPI);
   [myMapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(myCurrentLocationCordinate, 500.0, 500.0) animated:NO];
```

There is no need to use this line

```
MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(myCurrentLocationCordinate, 500, 500);
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [myMapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];
```

Hope it works and thanks to **@Firoze Lafeer** to help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

I handle my mapView zoom this way. Could you try it this way?

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.741168, 30.333555);
MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 0.5* 1609.344, 0.5* 1609.344);

[self.myMapview setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];
[self.myMapview setDelegate:self];
```